# Understanding String.fromCharCode() and detecting CTRTL + SHIFT + ]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect when a combination of key using EN international keyboard is being held, in my case:

`CTRL+SHIFT+]` the resulting Character Key Pressed should be `}`

`CTRL+]` the resulting Character Key Pressed should be `]`

Using the following code (just for testing) I get always Character Key Pressed `Û`. When using "normal" alphabetic characters I can see no problem.

Example:
https://jsbin.com/navihijuhe/edit?html,output

I kindly ask yuo:
- Why this problem?
- Could you provide me an example showing how to properly grab keys combination (CTRL-SHIFT-]) and run a routine?

Note: my OS is not EN international.